# Is the expression "wear the pants" outdated?

Tags: phrase-usage, politeness

Is the expression "wear the pants" in relationship somehow outdated, because women too wear pants nowadays?

The other day I jokingly said to my colleague and her fiancee "Who wears the pants here." but now I wonder if that expression is politically incorrect these days. I still see it in magazine articles and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, a Google Ngram shows that it's quite common, probably even growing on the whole: "[who wears the pants](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+wears+the+pants&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwho%20wears%20the%20pants%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwho%20wears%20the%20pants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWho%20wears%20the%20pants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWho%20Wears%20the%20Pants%3B%2Cc0)".

[image: who wears the pants]

Of course, it could be ironic for the  reason you point out. In any case, I haven't yet seen anyone get offended by the expression. Unless the person you're talking to is concerned about social justice implicit in daily language (and some people are), we rarely consider the origin of the idioms we use. When someone says "Who wears the pants?" usually the listener simply hears "Who's in charge?"

In general, metaphorical expressions outlive the literal images they employ. Thanks at least partly to *A Christmas Carol* by Charles Dickens, we still say "dead as a doornail", even though people don't put nails in their doors anymore and we don't talk about hardware as alive or dead anyway.

Comment: Interesting results! I assumed that people may have become more attentive to the language that includes social justice elements. Thank you for sharing your research results and for the detailed explanation.